# How to put items into grouped arrays where grouped by a particular key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am pretty new in Objects in JS, so I will need some help. I have the following Array:

```
var persons = [
    { fname : 'Steven', lname : 'Jameson', age : 20 },
    { fname : 'George', lname : 'Thrump', age : 40 },
    { fname : 'Peter', lname : 'Jacobs', age : 60 },
    { fname : 'Peter', lname : 'Thrump', age : 20 },
    { fname : 'Steven', lname : 'Henderson', age : 40 },
    { fname : 'John', lname : 'Jacobs', age : 30 },
    { fname : 'Steven', lname : 'Thrump', age : 50 },
    { fname : 'George', lname : 'Peterson', age : 40 },
    { fname : 'Peter', lname : 'Jameson', age : 60 }
];
```

I need to sort the information by a given property. I've tried with `function( array, 'property' )`. In my case it will be `function(persons, 'fname')`. I have to achieve an Object with keys the **different names** and that keys to store the information about everyone with that name. For example:

```
Object {
    Steven : everyone with first name Steven,
    George : everyone with first name George,
    Peter : everyone with first name Peter,
    John : everyone with first name John
}
```

I achieve this:

```
function group( array, property ) {
        var object = {};

        for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
            object[persons[i][property]] = [];

            object[persons[i][property]].push(persons[i])
        };
    };
```

Creating the object with the different names as keys, and giving them Array as value. And then I am stuck and don't know what to do next ? Can someone help and if he has few minutes to explain a bit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So now you want to sort on the keys of the object? That's impossible, you only can sort arrays.

Comment: You mention needing to sort, but then really talk about grouping these objects.  Do you need to do some form of sorting as well as grouping, or simply grouping? I don't fully understand what you are stuck on.

Comment: You need to initialize the array for each key only once, currently you're overwriting it. Change to `if (! (persons[i][property] in object)) object[persons[i][property]] = [];`

Comment: Changed title to reflect what is actually being asked and removed reference to sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only issue seems to be with this line:

```
object[persons[i][property]] = [];
```

It executes for every iteration, resetting each `Array` back to empty before adding 1 element. It just needs a condition before setting:

```
if (!(persons[i][property] in object))
    object[persons[i][property] = [];

object[persons[i][property].push(persons[i]);
```

Comment: But not that condition, please. Nonexistant properties are not `null`

Comment: +1 (@Bergi and Jonathan) Another problem : the array should be called `array` not `persons` in the function.

Comment: `if (!object[persons[i][property]])` will do.

Comment: @Jonathan: Checking with the `in` operator or using `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: I'd sooner see `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, persons[i][property])`

Comment: not that you're ever likely to have a person named `hasOwnProperty` or `constructor`, but it's a loophole worth mentioning

Answer (score 1):

You should check if `object[persons[i][property]]` is already initialize

```
 function group( persons, property ) {
    var object = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
        if(!object[persons[i][property]]) {
            object[persons[i][property]] = [];
     }

      object[persons[i][property]].push(persons[i])
    };
    return object;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function group(array, property) {
    var object = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var person = array[i];
        if (person[property]) {
            object[person[property]] = object[person[property]] || [];
            object[person[property]].push(person);
        }
    };

    return object;
};

group(persons, "fname");
```